# How can I get all the data from References using Firebase Database Plugin

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dart, flutter

I'm using the Firebase Database plugin to Flutter and I'm trying to get all the data from the "schedules" row.

I have this code and I'm already connected to the Firebase server.

```
  FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('schedules');
```

My data is stored like this:
[screenshot of Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TZ7y.png)

I wanted to get the data and insert it on a List so I can use it later.

The data have to be stored like this in Firebase because I need all those 3 values together when I get them. I also wonder if using the Firebase plugin the users will have the ability to update the data (if it is the case) when connected to the internet and see it even when disconnected. Before that I was using `httpRequests`, but I decided to not use a local storage manager and just see if this plugin could do this for me.

If it can do that, what would be the right way to get all the children data from "schedules" using flutter? (the data is not displayed as a list, so I can't use `FirebaseAnimatedList`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use a `StreamBuilder` so that the sections of your app that rely on the list of schedules will automatically rebuild when the data changes.

```
  return new StreamBuilder<Event>(
    stream: FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('schedules').onValue,
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Event> event) {
      if (!event.hasData)
        return new Center(child: new Text('Loading...'));
      Map<String, Map> schedules = event.data.snapshot.value;
      // Do something with the list of schedules
    },
  ),
```

If for some reason you only want to get the schedules list once, use `once()` instead of `onValue` and `await` its value.

Comment: I get this error:  '_InternalLinkedHashMap' is not of subtype of type 'List<Map>' of  'schedules'

Comment: I fixed the error by changing List<Map> to Map<String, Map>. Got it up and running!

Comment: I edited my answer to use the correct type. Glad it was helpful!